# Issue with xorg-server on arch

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, emacs

After a arch linux upgrade, it seems that my x-server is really unstable... Launching emacs with exwm does not work anymore. I have installed gnome and it does work (sometimes, very unstable). I downgrade my system with pacman, but x-server still does not work.

When the x server fails, here the log file:

```
Time: Tue Nov 26 22:12:45 2019
[   567.803] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   567.803] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   567.803] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   567.803] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   567.803] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   567.803] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   567.803] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   567.803] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   567.803] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   567.803] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   567.803] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   567.803] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[   567.803]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   567.803] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[   567.803]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   567.803] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[   567.803]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   567.803] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[   567.803]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   567.803] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[   567.803]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   567.803] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF
[   567.803] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   567.803] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   567.803] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   567.803]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   567.803]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   567.803]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   567.803]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   567.804] (++) using VT number 2

[   567.805] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33
[   567.806] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   567.806] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card0: Operation not permitted
[   567.807] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[   567.808] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0a16:17aa:3978 rev 9, Mem @ 0xb0000000/4194304, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00003000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   567.808] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[   567.808] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   567.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   567.809] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   567.809]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[   567.809]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   567.809] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[   567.809] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   567.809] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   567.809] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   567.809] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   567.809] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   567.809] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   567.810] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   567.810]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 2.99.917
[   567.810]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   567.810]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   567.810] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   567.810] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   567.810] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   567.810]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.20.5
[   567.810]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   567.810]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   567.810] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   567.810] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[   567.810] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   567.810] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   567.810] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[   567.810] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[   567.810] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   567.810] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   567.810] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   567.810] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   567.810] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   567.811] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   567.811] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20190619
[   567.811] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled from 2.99.917-893-gbff5eca4
[   567.827] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   567.827] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   570.107] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[   570.107] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
[   570.107] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[   570.107] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   570.107] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   570.107] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   570.107] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   570.107] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/tuedachu/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[   570.107] (EE) 
[   570.130] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

My configuration worked fine before the system upgrade.

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks.

Arnaud